# Sumarize AWS CloudWatch Logs data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a log group on CloudWatch with some LogStreams which have events in JSON format.

Something like:

```
{ "dimension1": "foo", "dimension2": "bar", "metric1": 12, "metric2": 20 }
{ "dimension1": "anything", "dimension2": "other", "metric1": 20, "metric2": 12 }
{ "dimension1": "foo", "dimension2": "other", "metric1": 10, "metric2": 12 }
...
{ "dimension1": "foo", "dimension2": "other", "metric1": 12, "metric2": 20 }
```

I have to sumarize those events calculating their averages, counts and sums over some dimension sets, through some specific time windows, and write them anywhere I can read it easily (S3, or something like).

I expect to obtain a result like:

```
{ "dimension1": "foo", "dimension2": "other": "metric1_count": 2, "metric1_avg": 11, "metric1_min": 10, "metric1_max": 12 }
...
{ "dimension1": "foo", "dimension2": "bar": "metric1_count": 1, "metric1_avg": 12, "metric1_min": 12, "metric1_max": 12 }
```

I know how to do it by reading the data with CloudWatch Logs API, consolidate using Redis as an intermediate store, or even keeping data in memory while consolidating it, and after all write the summaries to S3, but I would like to know if it´s possible to achieve the same result using any AWS service writing less code, and keeping the solution simpler than creating a Lambda or anything like.